# Search not displaying results

Tags: search

I can't seem to get any results to show up, even though I know for a fact that the content exists! Here's my code (search.php)

```
 <?php
/* Template Name: Search */


get_template_part('./template/global/header');
?>

<!--content -->
<div id="content">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="breadcrumbs"><?php
if (function_exists('bcn_display')) {
    bcn_display();
}
?></div>
        <?php
        $sidebar = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'wpcf-sidebar-template', true);
        if ($sidebar == 'disable') {
            ?>
            <style type="text/css">
                #page {
                    width:100% !important;
                }

            </style>
        <?php }
        ?>
        <section id="page">
            <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
            <?php
            get_search_form();
            if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post();
                    the_content();
                endwhile;
            else:
                ?>
                <p><?php _e('Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.'); ?></p>
            <?php endif;
            ?>

        </section>

        <?php
        if (function_exists('dynamic_sidebar')) {
            if (!($sidebar)) {
                if (is_admin()) {
                    echo _e('No sidebar preferences are defined.');
                }
            } else {

                if ($sidebar != 'disable') {
                    echo '<aside id="sidebar">';
                    get_template_part('./template/misc/sidebar-banner');
                    dynamic_sidebar('sidebar-' . $sidebar);
                    echo '</aside>';
                }
            }
        }
        ?>

        <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
    <!--/content --> 
    <?php
    get_template_part('./template/global/footer');
```

Comment: Do you see 'Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.'?

Comment: Yup, the query is empty.... search refuses to work for some reason.

Comment: The search happens before that page loads. The problem is elsewhere, but I don't know where. Disable plugins and switch themes and try to narrow it down.

Comment: the global query seems to be altered somewhere.try debugging if you have made `new wp_query()` before try resetting it with `wp_reset_query()` or if you have used `query_post()` use wp_query instead

Comment: try to search for functions that hook with `pre_get_posts`, to me there is some function that alters search query: `$query->is_search`